# Three.js - Double side sphere texture but opacity should be lower of backside

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making a sphere wrapped around by a texture of a world map and want it to be double sided. The problem is both the front and back sides are of same opacity which is creating confusion. So I want the backside of the texture to be of lower opacity than front side to ease the difference. Help me find a solution. Thanks.

```
var globeTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("/texture/dotmap.png")

var globeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: globeTexture,
        shininess: 40,
        transparent: true,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        opacity: 1,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
        color: 0xaaaaaa,
        blending : THREE.AdditiveBlending
});

var mesh = new THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, [globeMaterial]);

return mesh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. 
It was about creating front side and back side separately and then managing the properties separately of each side.

```
      var globeTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("/texture/dotmap.png")

      var globeMaterialf = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: globeTexture,
        shininess: 40,
        transparent: true,
        side: THREE.FrontSide,
        opacity: 0.9,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
        color: 0xaaaaaa,
        blending : THREE.AdditiveBlending
      });

      var globeMaterialb = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        map: globeTexture,
        transparent: true,
        side: THREE.BackSide,
        opacity: 0.1,
        shading: THREE.SmoothShading,
        color: 0xaaaaaa,
        blending : THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        depthTest: false
      });

      var mesh = new THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, [globeMaterialf, globeMaterialb]);
```